# How to add click actionListener to document?

Tags: jsf, jstl

I understand we can add `actionListener` to `commandButton` as:

```
<h:commandButton value="ClickMe">
    <f:actionListener type="com.mycompany.MyActionListener" />
</h:commandButton>
```

But how can I add an `actionListener` to document (entire document, not just body)? The reason I am doing this is when user clicks on anywhere in the page, I want to trigger a method.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery for click detection:

```
$(document).click(function(e) { 
    // control if it is the left button
    if (e.button == 0) {
        functionToTrigger();
   }
});
```

... and a hidden `h:commandButton` if you want to trigger the method synchronously, or (preferably) `a4j:jsFunction` to trigger it asynchronously:

```
<a4j:jsFunction name="functionToTrigger"
    execute="@this"
    actionListener="#{myManagedBean.myAction}"/>
```